# Using the IChannelActionPolicy to build a ChannelReconnectOnTimeoutPolicy

Tags: castle-windsor, wcffacility

I'm trying to recreate the sample provided on the castle windsor wiki about **channel action policies** (found here: http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.WCF-Facility-Channel-Action-Policy.ashx ) but i can't seem to find **IChannelActionPolicy** interface in the Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration namespace anywhere. 
I've installed the wcf facility via Nuget.

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is outdated in this regard. Have a look at `IWcfPolicy` interface and its implementors